# SELECT DISTINCT user_id of highest value in support_date WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, max, distinct, where-clause

*tb_supporters*:

```
user_id          support_date
-----------------------------
   1              1301283373
   2              1301283743
   3              1301799207
   1              1403862904
   2              1405174895
   3              1415266390
```

As the result of the query, it should output the highest support_date of each unique user_id.

My actual query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), support_date
 FROM tb_supporters WHERE
 support_date < " . (time() - 60*60*24*7)
```

However, it's not selecting the highest support_date beside the user_id.
Tried with `MAX(support_date)`, `GROUP BY user_id`, `ORDER BY support_date DESC`, but nothing helped and it's still selecting the lowest support_date only.

Would you please lead me into the right direction how to accomplish this task to select only the highest support_date beside each user_id?

The result should be:

```
user_id          support_date
-----------------------------
   1              1403862904
   2              1405174895
   3              1415266390
```

The WHERE clause in my query is to keep out user_ids where the support_date is inside a range of the past 7 days.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** existing user_ids within this 7 days range I don't want to be selected at all, not even with their highest support_date.

Comment: Have you tried this way `select user_id,max(support_date) as support_date from table group by user_id order by user_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The WHERE clause in my query is to **keep out** user_ids where the
>   support_date is **inside** a range of the past 7 days.

You can rephrase it like this:

> The WHERE clause in my query is to **select** user_ids where highest
>   support_date is **outside** a range of the past 7 days.

You can use `GROUP BY` and `MAX` with a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT user_id, MAX(support_date)
FROM tb_supporters
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(support_date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Note that you cannot use a `WHERE` clause for this because it will eliminate the **rows** where user support is within past 7 days; not the **groups**.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Table

```
CREATE Table table_sample(id INT, date INT);
```

Some INSERT's

```
INSERT INTO table_sample VALUES(1,1301283373);
INSERT INTO table_sample VALUES(2,1301283743);
INSERT INTO table_sample VALUES(3,1301799207);
INSERT INTO table_sample VALUES(1,1403862904);
INSERT INTO table_sample VALUES(2,1405174895);
INSERT INTO table_sample VALUES(3,1415266390);

SELECT * FROM table_sample;
+------+------------+
| id   | date       |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 1301283373 |
|    2 | 1301283743 |
|    3 | 1301799207 |
|    1 | 1403862904 |
|    2 | 1405174895 |
|    3 | 1415266390 |
+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Your query 

SELECT id,MAX(date) FROM table_sample GROUP BY id;
+------------+------+
|  id |MAX(date)  |
+------------+------+
| 1   |  1403862904 |
| 2   |  1405174895 |
| 3   |  1415266390 |
+------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To find date is inside a range of the past 7 days , you can do

```
SELECT id,MAX(date) FROM table_sample WHERE date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) GROUP BY id;
+------+------------+
| id   | MAX(date)  |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 1403862904 |
|    2 | 1405174895 |
|    3 | 1415266390 |
+------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Would you have a look at my updated question please? I need all user_id's inside the 7 days range not listed at all. Only those outside should be selected

Comment: You want data that is not of past 7 days ? Your 7 days range starts from current date ?

Comment: I need the data older than 7 days, but not with user_id's that are part of the 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT user_id,max(support_date) as support_date 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY user_id    
ORDER BY support_date DESC
```

Comment: Would you have a look at my updated question please? I need all user_id's inside the 7 days range not listed at all. Only those user_id's outside their highest support_date regarding the WHERE clause should be selected

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, max(date) FROM tb_supporters group by id;

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use default MySQL function for unix timestamp

```
SELECT 
    user_id, MAX(support_date)
FROM
    tb_supporters
WHERE
    support_date < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Your answer is the closest, however I still get user_id's that are inside the WHERE clause. Any idea?

Comment: You can add in where condition like `user_id IN (1 , 2)` or `user_id = 3` and it will be ok. Also if you need range in last seven days you can use this condition: `support_date BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`